# Puppeteer ignoring proxy locally but not on server?

Tags: proxy, puppeteer

I'm getting a 1020 HTTP error executing the same code locally, I just made the update Big Sur to Monterey. This happens with both headful and headless modes.

Same code still works well in Ubuntu remote server and I can access the site through proxy. Even tried to match node version and reinstalled packages.

Any ideas why this might be happening?